# Getting SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h' while installing numpy==1.20.3

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, homebrew, python

My Mac was bought in 2015 with macOS Catalina. I was trying to install numpy 1.20.3 but during installation I got the below error in Terminal:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

I installed numpy using these steps:

- Installed python using brew
- Installed pip using python
- Installed numpy using `pip install numpy==1.20.3`

I followed [this Stack Overflow link to install python-devel in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578106/how-to-install-python-devel-in-mac-os) to verify whether to install python-devel separately, but this links points that when one installs python using brew, python-devel will be installed automatically.

My question is that if installing python using brew will automatically install python-devel, then why I am getting this issue?

Comment: How did you install Python? How do you try to install numpy?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode? There are several ways to get this working but I suspect the simplest is to use [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/)

Comment: @nohillside i am trying to install numpy using pip

Comment: @mmmmmm, as i have installed brew hence xcode ins installed. I will try to use ananconda and see does it solve the issue

Comment: Note pip and python are  probably python2 - you should be using python3 as python2 is not supported by python.org

Comment: Python2 will also mit be part of the next macOS update.

Comment: @mmmmmm I was using pip3 and python3 only.